# Vlocity Omniscript using Docusign and Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Good Afternoon. I hope everyone is ok.

I was wondering if someone could help me. I am using DocuSign within a Vlocity Omniscript.  We have set up DocuSign action, which works perfectly and generates the Docusign. The issue we are facing, when an envelope ID for DocuSign is created, does this get stored within Salesforce. I am trying to find how DocuSign works with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

To integration DocuSign and Salesforce, see the [DocuSign for Salesforce](https://www.docusign.com/solutions/salesforce) product line.